# Siu's arguments on Calabi-Yau theorem?

Tags: complex-geometry, elliptic-pde, kahler-einstein-metric

In Siu's lecture note [Lectures on Hermitian-Einstein metrics for stable bundles and Kähler-Einstein metrics](http://math.harvard.edu/~siu/siu_reprints/dmv_book.pdf), he shows the $C^0$ and $C^2$ estimates of the complex Monge-Ampère equation on a Riemannian manifold (actually, a Kähler manifold).

Then, Siu uses Evans-Krylov's arguments to show Hölder estimates for the second derivatives. But in Chapter Two §4 (p75) of the his note, he says that "let $u$ be a real-valued function on an open subset of $\mathbb{C}^m$", that is, he treats the equation in complex euclidean space.

My question is why it suffices to show the $C^{2,\alpha}$ estimate in euclidean space instead of the Riemannian manifold.

Comment: he is just working in a chart on the manifold, which can be identified with an open subset of $\mathbb{C}^m$. What is your question?

Comment: @YangMills Another question is why we have to get C^0 and C^2 estimates in manifold language.

Comment: people do what they can... nobody knows a purely local interior $C^2$ estimate for the complex Monge-Ampere equation, except in very special cases (e.g. ball in Euclidean space with $0$ boundary data) which are not sufficient here. As for $C^0$ there are indeed "almost local" versions of this estimate using the ABP method, see e.g. http://gamma.im.uj.edu.pl/~blocki/publ/unif.pdf, where you just work in a chart centered at a global minimum point (but they require a global $L^p$ bound for some $p>0$, even very small)